# htaccess follows the previous rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to achieve the following with htaccess.

Redirect 301 Domain1/menu1/ Domain2/menu1/

Redirect 301 Domain1/menu1/submenu1 Domain2/menu2

But it remembers the previous rule and put between the menu1 in the second rule like Domain2/menu1/menu2.

How I can avoid this and every rule not follow the rest of the rules?

Thanks in advance.

I have tried all the possibilities but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the two rules. The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is prefix matching, so the first rule matches a request for `/menu1/submenu1` and everything after the *match* is appended onto the target.

But you also can't match the "domain" using the `Redirect` directive. It matches against the URL-path only.

See the Apache docs:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Answer (score 0):

You must not include the `Domain1`. It should look like this:

```
Redirect 301 /menu1/ Domain2/menu1/
```

The documentation of [mod_alias#Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) says:

> Then any request beginning with URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.

The first of your rules will also match for all cases you would like your second rule to fit. So the second rule is never matched.

To get your second rule (with the deeper path) active instead of the first one, you have to exchange the order:

```
Redirect 301 /menu1/submenu1 Domain2/menu2
Redirect 301 /menu1/ Domain2/menu1/
```

Like this the less deep one will match for all fitting cases that do not match the deeper one.